# how to capture when java application is quit?

Tags: java, log4j, exit

How can i get `log4j` to log to a file on application exit. currently i am using the below when application is starting, but not sure how to capture on application exit

```
logger.info("Starting application....");
```

Comment: this may help: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/dwalend/archive/2004/05/shutdown_hooks_2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to register a shutdown hook

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your thing
    }
}));
```

Note that this will only get executed if the [program ends naturally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202154/how-many-ways-a-java-program-can-end).

Answer (score 3):

Use a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // log here
    });
```